# Convert ByteArrayOutputStream to int values

Tags: java, android, bytearrayoutputstream

I am constantly trying to convert a **ByteArrayOutputStream to int values.**

I am recording an Audio with microphone and writing it to `out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()` like so:

```
out.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

`byte audio[] = out.toByteArray();`

When I print this I get these : [B@3456337e

How do I convert these to integer numbers.

Please Help, Thanks

Comment: Do you want to print the byte array, or really want to convert it to int array?

Comment: int array sir @kupsef

Comment: So you want to convert each block of four bytes into a signed integer?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to do it because actually it depends on what kind of bytes you have but, as it is an audio source, I think you can do it like that :

```
IntBuffer intBuf =
   ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)
     .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) //or try ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN
     .asIntBuffer();
 int[] array = new int[intBuf.remaining()];
 intBuf.get(array);
 //The result you want is "array"
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry i didnt understand well, what should i print to get my integer array here ? i printed intBuf.get(array); and i got java.nio.ByteBufferAsIntBufferB[pos=11025 lim=11025 cap=11025]

what i need is a single numbers between 0 - 256 @user3733356

Comment: yes sorry, i forgot to tell you that the result is "array". Print "array" and you will have what you want

Comment: printed array, got [I@629bee3a, i guess is another byte

Comment: @user3464035 Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`.

Comment: @Duncan I get bunch of 0,0,0,0,0,0
because the audio is fluctuating i should get numbers like 100, 80, 34,...

Comment: @user3464035 It works for me. Perhaps your input data isn't what you think it is. You could try printing your input data with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(audio));` - maybe it's all zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an array, wrap the array in a `ByteArrayInputStream`, wrap that in a `DataInputStream,` and use `readInt().`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
         ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         DataInputStream dataIs = new DataInputStream
              (new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());


         // available stream to be read
         while(dataIs.available()>0)
         {

            int k = dataIs.readInt();

            // print int
            System.out.print(k+" ");
         }
```